# Why did Peter the Great change his daughters' title to Tsesarevna?

Tags: russia, royalty, titles, peter-i-russia

Having won the Great Northern War in 1721, **Peter the Great** promoted himself from Tsar to Emperor. At the same time, he seems to have changed the title used by his daughters from **Tsarevna** to **Tsesarevna**. (By symmetry, it seems that he would have changed the title used by any son of his from Tsarevich to Tsesarevich, although by this point he had already had his last surviving son, Alexei, tortured to death.) **What was his rationale for doing this?**

My own best guess is that the change in his daughters' titles reflected the change in his own title; Tsarevna meant something like *royal princess*, whereas Tsesarevna meant something like *imperial princess*, at least in Peter's mind. According to this theory, the Tsesar- corresponds to the English/Latin Caesar, i.e. Emperor, and the -evna suffix, of course, means daughter. However, I can see two problems with this point of view:

1. The word Tsar is itself derived from the title of Caesar.
2. The Russian transliteration of Caesar is Цезарь, whereas the Russian spelling of Tsesarevna is Цесаревна; note that the former uses the letter з where the latter uses the letter с.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: As a side comment to your bullet 2, spelling Цесарь was also common, see e.g. https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/цѣсарь or https://lexicography.online/explanatory/dal/ц/цесарь (Dal's dictionary). I would even suppose that spelling with "з" is relatively recent; Dal's dictionary seems to include *only* "цесарь". Also, "кесарь" was common and is still used in some phrases.

Comment: Also, Russian Wikipedia has some explanation: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Цесаревич#При_Петре_I , with a quote from Solovyov's History of Russia.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your main question, but the fact that two words (царь and Цесар) come from the same root doesn't mean they don't have different significance in the receptor language. For example, *Caesar*, *czar*, *tsar*, and *kaiser* have different meanings (or at least strong connotations) in English, although they all ultimately come from the same root.

Comment: You can ask this question in russian.se.  It is more about language than history.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When Peter 'upgraded' the Russian title of '[tsar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Russian_monarchs#Tsars_of_Russia,_1547%E2%80%931721)' (царь) to '[emperor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor_of_All_Russia)' (император), this meant that the corresponding titles would have to be given a similar jump upwards.

The specific issue arose because the Westernized 'emperor', though sharing its root with the Slavonized 'tsar' in the Latin 'caesar', was a more important title than that of tsar, the two not being synonymous. In the previously used 'tsarevich' the suffix ['-vich' ('-евич')](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87#Russian) indicates 'son of'—hence, the meaning of the title is 'son of tsar'.

**Therefore, 'tsarevich' (царе́вич) or '[son](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87#Russian) of tsar' was unsuitable for someone who was the son of an emperor. Hence, '[tsesarevich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsesarevich)' (цесаре́вич) or 'son of emperor' was created to remedy that problem. The female variant 'tsarevna' (царевна) was similarly unsuitable for 'daughter of emperor' for which the more apt 'tsesarevna' (цесаре́вна) was created.** Their meanings in translation, in this case, are less important than the words in Russian which express a filial relationship towards the ruler because the translations are a matter of convention.

A similar translation problem arises with 'velikiy knyaz' which can be rendered as 'Grand Prince' or 'Grand Duke'—both being correct—which could also be accorded to the scions of the imperial house.

Comment: Let me be clear - I upvoted and I would accept this answer if it were my question (Speaking as a Russian student for many years).  What I'm looking for is something that goes beyond tertiary etymological sources - something like a primary source that documents the decision to change the titles/create new title based on the Emperor's elevation.  (not sure I'm expressing that clearly.)  You've answered the "Why", but not the "when" or the "who". - but a splendid answer

Comment: Plus knyaz being cognate to German König/King… So yeah. But why the trouble of upgrading the Russian title, given that he could just insist on an elevated rank translation, or heck, just use inRussian one of those new fangled westernised words altogether (given his other preferences, and the Russian ease with which they import foreign words)?

Answer (score -2):

> What was his rationale for doing this?

Seems like a simple Westernization of Russian official vocabulary, which was a mainstream policy of Peter I. This was a message to the European leaders about the emerging Russian power and its global ambitions, so it was phrased in terms well understood in the West. I doubt that "Tsesar" communicates any greater status than "Tsar", it simply speaks to Western ears.

Comment: Welcome to HSE. Is that just a conjecture? Or are you aware of some proof?

Comment: Why is the entire answer formatted as a quote? If it is a quote, where is it taken from?

Comment: @F1Krazy: Thanks for fixing the format.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Sorry, no references, just common sense. Which sentence in my answer you find arguable?: 1) westernization of vocabulary? 2) new title is a message to the neighbors? 3) "tsar" == "tsesar"? Thanks.

Comment: @user48117 Being “a message to the European leaders about the emerging Russian power and its global ambitions”.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Any title is a message to public. True even in our days. Russia has just defeated the best army in Europe, securing its claim to the eastern Baltic shore and becoming a factor in European politics. The ambitions of Peter the Great to turn Russians into a sea faring nation are well known, this is why he fought for access to Baltic and Black seas. I admit that adjective "global" may be too strong, I meant to say that Russia became a subject of European politics rather than being just an object.